# handling infinite loop in apache-kafka consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

iam new to kafka i want to implement a kafka message pipeline system for our play-scala project,i created a  topic in which records are inserted, and i wrote a consumer code like this,

```
val recordBatch = new ListBuffer[CountryModel]
  consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("session-queue"))
    while (true) {
      val records = consumer.poll(1000)
      val iter = records.iterator()
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        val record: ConsumerRecord[String, String] = iter.next()
        recordBatch += Json.parse(record.value()).as[CountryModel]
      }
     processData(recordBatch)
     // Thread.sleep(5 * 1000)
    }

but after certain time  the service is stopping, the processor is going to 100% after certain time machine is stopping, how can i handle this infinite loop.
```

in production environment i can not rely on this loop right  i tried to sleep the thread for some time  but it is not a elegant solution

Comment: May have a look to https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka.